# What is the value of $(this) on an unnamed html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I could not find an answer for this. So I hope it's not redundant..

Have a simple form element:

```
<label>Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" onblur="validateEmail(this)" />
```

And I'm running a validation script to check whether this input value (onBlur) is valid.  Works great!

Now.. what I'm trying to do is keep the script universal - so I do not have to rely on class names or IDs to make it work.

So what I want to know is how to take action on this field if the value is NOT an email address.  Specifically, I want change the color of the label and put a red border on the field itself.

Here's the script that does not work:

```
var inputTextTest = field.value;
var filter = /^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*?)\s*;?\s*)+/;

if ( filter.test(inputTextTest) ) {
    var name = field;
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).css("border","1px");
    $(this).css("border-color","red");
} else {
    $(this).css("border", "none");
}
```

I can see that my call to $(this) isn't working.  So how do I take action on this particular field and keep the script totally universal (i.e., not dependent on specific classes or ID names)?

Thanks to all in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have to use obtrusive javascript?

Comment: Use of `this` is independent of whether the target element has a name or not. Name/id/class or just the type of element can be used for selection, such that event handler(s) can be attached. Within an event handler `this` refers to the target element. If the selectors were correct and the handler is runs when an appropriate event happens, then the selector **must** have done its job. 'this' cares not what selector allowed the handler to be attached. Maybe it's me but the question doesn't make sense. Moreover, the question's title and text don't seem to correspond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll guess that the parameter referencing `this` is `field`, as you're using `field.value` at the top there :

```
validateEmail(field) {
    var inputTextTest = field.value;
    var filter = /^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*?)\s*;?\s*)+/;

    if ( filter.test(inputTextTest) ) {
        var name = field.name;
        $(field).focus().css("border","1px solid red");
    } else {
        $(field).css("border", "none");
    }
}
```

Comment: Vote for this, in the same way you have retrieved value go back and make modifications.

Comment: This did it.. Thanks adeneo.  I knew it must have been something simple.  And using "this" in the onBlur call is the only way it will function.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

try`field` instead of `this` assuming function declaration looks like `validateEmail(field)`

Within `onblur` you are passing `this` as object to function but then need to usee whatever param name you used when you declared the function arguments

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it generic I'd suggest you use one of the existing validation libraries:

https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate#readme

The reason $(this) doesn't work for you is because it isn't defined, you aren't in a callback or a function that has created the reference.

To do a generic loop and use $(this) you'd need to do something like this:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this)  // will now reference each element.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the script in a function and take the object as argument then perform everything on the object.